# How can I add AdSense code to my ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adsense

I am setting up AdSense to my web application. I was given an AdSense code to paste into the HTML of my website, between the  and  tags. But I am using ASP.NET MVC for the website. Please, how do I go about using this AdSense code on my website?

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
   google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5888633898042518",
   enable_page_level_ads: true
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Your view files file can contain raw HTML and JavaScript no problem

Comment: Okay. Thanks, @ADyson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to your `_Layout.cshtml` file, on the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

In razor AdsComponent something like this.

```
<h3>AdsComponent</h3>
<div>
    @Ads
</div>
@code {
    private RenderFragment Ads
    {
        get
        {
            RenderFragment form = b =>
            {
                b.OpenElement(0, "script");
                b.AddAttribute(0, "async", true);
                b.AddAttribute(0, "src", "https://pagead2/googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
                b.CloseElement();
                b.OpenElement(0, "ins");
                b.AddAttribute(0, "class", "adsbygoogle");
                b.AddAttribute(1, "style", "display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px");
                b.AddAttribute(2, "data-ad-client", "ca-pub-988649660289431");
                b.AddAttribute(3, "data-ad-slot", "4069520508");
                //Test
                b.AddAttribute(4, "data-adtest", "on");

                b.CloseElement();
                b.OpenElement(0, "script");
                b.AddContent(0, "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});");
                b.CloseElement();
            };
            return form;
        }
    }
}
```